# How to select common values in multiple data frames in R?

Tags: r

I am new to R. I have 3 data frames as

```
a1
1 p53
2 NFKB
3 P73
4 P21
5 PTEN

a2
1 p21
2 p53
3 ERGIC3
4 MAP3K3
5 PTEN

a3
1 PTEN
2 MAP3K3
3 ERGIC3
4 AURKA
5 p53
```

I have get a table as the output showing only the common values like p53 and PTEN which is common in all the three data frames. How should I write the code in R?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want, since you haven't provided a reporoducible example, but maybe you want something like `df1[, intersect(names(df1), names(df2), names(df3))]`

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Reduce` and `intersect` in a one-liner.

I assume `a1`, `a2`, `a3` are really `data.frame`s (and not `vector`s). Then do:

```
common_elements <- Reduce(intersect, list(a1[, 1], a2[, 1], a3[, 1]));
common_elements;
#[1] "p53"  "PTEN"
```

If instead `a1`, `a2`, `a3` were vectors, you'd do

```
common_elements <- Reduce(intersect, list(a1, a2, a3));
common_elements;
```

---

### Sample data

```
a1 <- read.table(text =
    "a1
1 p53
2 NFKB
3 P73
4 P21
5 PTEN", header = T)

a2 <- read.table(text = 
    "a2
1 p21
2 p53
3 ERGIC3
4 MAP3K3
5 PTEN", header = T)

a3 <- read.table(text = 
    "a3
1 PTEN
2 MAP3K3
3 ERGIC3
4 AURKA
5 p53", header = T)
```

Comment: Down-votes are a bit harsh, considering that this is a valid solution, and I posted this prior to the dupe flag.